# Saving Dropdown Options with Handsontable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, handsontable

I have an ajax call set on a column in my Handsontable to return options stored in my database.

```
columns: [
    {data: 'firstName'},
    {data: 'lastName'},
    {data: 'department',  
        type: 'dropdown',
        strict: false, 
        source: function(query, process){ 
            $.ajax({
            url: '/getDepartments',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
              var values = [];
              for (i in response) values.push(response[i].name);
              process(values);
            }
        });
    }
```

My list of Departments populates fine, however I need to send the ID of the department when I'm persisting any changes (as this ID is a foreign key in my User's Table). I'm wondering how to achieve this with HOT - Do they provide a method to bind an int value to a string for cases such as this?

I was also thinking I could store the ID in a hidden cell, but I'm reading more into the API before I create more work than I need to

Answer (score 1):

A hidden cell is the way to go here. The typical solution is simply to keep that hidden cell as part of your data object and hide it by not defining it in the `columns` definition. There is no other way yet to bind IDs to a row using HOT.

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://github.com/trebuchetty/Handsontable-select2-editor to solve this problem.

You have to include the .js file provided in the repo and define the customDropdownRenderer required.

```
function customDropdownRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties)
{
    var selectedId;
    for (var index = 0; index < optionsList.length; index++)
    {
        if (parseInt(value) === optionsList[index].id)
        {
            selectedId = optionsList[index].id;
            value = optionsList[index].text;            
        }
    }
    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    // you can use the selectedId for posting to the DB or server
    $('#selectedId').text(selectedId);
}
```

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/trebuchetty/tLp0dnga/